# Anaconda Navigator doesn't open either Jupyter Notebook or Jupyter Lab on Windows 7

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, editor, navigator

I have installed Anaconda Navigator on my Window 7 64-bit. Navigator works because I was able to open Jupyter Notebook and Lab from it.

Now when I try to lunch one of the Jupyter (does not matter if it is Lab or Notebook), instead of the proper session, a text editor starts is opened (Sublime in my case) and shows me this file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;url=http://localhost:8888/tree?token=b489a168099142aa3c090200521df6abef06840b8416e0fb" />
    <title>Opening Jupyter Notebook</title>
    <script>
      setTimeout(function() {
        window.location.href = "http://localhost:8888/tree?token=b489a168099142aa3c090200521df6abef06840b8416e0fb";
      }, 1000);
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<p>
    This page should redirect you to Jupyter Notebook. If it doesn't,
    <a href="http://localhost:8888/tree?token=b489a168099142aa3c090200521df6abef06840b8416e0fb">click here to go to Jupyter</a>.
</p>

</body>
</html>
```

This file is stored in   AppData\Roaming\jupyter\runtime .

No error message is returned. However, I would like to fix this issue on my Anaconda Navigator.

I have already downloaded and installed the last version but I obtained the same result.

Comment: it can be problem with system (Windows) because it decides which program to use to open file.

Comment: Thanks furas, it was exactly the point. For some reason, my HTML files were redirected to Sublime. Instead, I changed the destination, through "Open with" option in the popup menu of the file, directly to Firefox. Now it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your .html files are set 'default' to open with sublime text editor.

If you use windows then this might help
1.Go to settings.
2.Search for default apps
3.find .html settings in choose default app by file type.
4.change it to the browser of your choice.
It should work.